# Add multiple columns using for loop in R and name with row entry

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have searched and can't find the answer to this, though it seems like a pretty basic R question.

I am trying to add multiple columns to a dataframe using a for loop. I would also like each column to be named with the row entry that it corresponds to.

Here is an example:

```
    > test <- data.frame(cbind(x=1, y=1:10))
    > test
    x  y
    1  1
    1  2
    1  3
    1  4
    1  5
    1  6
    1  7
    1  8
    1  9
    1 10
```

I then tried this:

```
    y <- test$y
    for (i in y) { test$i <- rep(c(test$y [i]), times=length(test$y)) }
```

which gave me this:

```
    > test
    x  y  i
    1  1 10
    1  2 10
    1  3 10
    1  4 10
    1  5 10
    1  6 10
    1  7 10
    1  8 10
    1  9 10
    1 10 10
```

However, what I wanted was this:

```
    > test
    x  y  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  3  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  6  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  8  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1  9  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    1 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd really appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: Use of `$` is tricky. Try  `test[[paste0(i)]] <-`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
v1 <- seq_len(nrow(test))
#or
#v1 <- test$y 
cbind(test,setNames(data.frame(as.list(v1)), v1))
#   x  y 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#1  1  1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#2  1  2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#3  1  3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#4  1  4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#5  1  5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#6  1  6 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#7  1  7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#8  1  8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#9  1  9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#10 1 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Or

```
test[paste(v1)] <- as.list(v1)
```